# Fetch Request Error - POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/predict 404 (Not Found)

Tags: flask, post, request, bots, chatbot

**Issue:**
I am building a chatbot application where I need to send a fetch request from my React frontend to a Flask backend's /predict endpoint. However, I'm encountering a "404 (Not Found)" error in the browser console when I click the "send" button on the chatbot.

**Context:**
Both my React frontend and Flask backend are running on the same port (port 3000), and I have confirmed that the /predict route is correctly defined in my Flask app.

**Expected Behavior:**
I expect the fetch request to successfully hit the /predict endpoint in my Flask app and receive a response containing the chatbot's answer.

**Code Snippets:**

app.js (React Frontend):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./style.css";

const Chatbox = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  const toggleState = (chatbox) => {
    setState(!state);

    // show or hide the box
    if (!state) {
      chatbox.classList.add("chatbox--active");
    } else {
      chatbox.classList.remove("chatbox--active");
    }
  };

  const onSendButton = (chatbox) => {
    var textField = chatbox.querySelector("input");
    let text1 = textField.value;
    if (text1 === "") {
      return;
    }

    let msg1 = { name: "User", message: text1 };
    setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, msg1]);

    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3000/predict", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: text1 }),
      mode: "cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((r) => {
        let msg2 = { name: "Sam", message: r.answer };
        setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, msg2]);
        updateChatText(chatbox);
        textField.value = "";
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
        updateChatText(chatbox);
        textField.value = "";
      });
  };

  const updateChatText = (chatbox) => {
    var html = "";
    messages
      .slice()
      .reverse()
      .forEach(function (item, index) {
        if (item.name === "Sam") {
          html += `<div class="messages__item messages__item--visitor">${item.message}</div>`;
        } else {
          html += `<div class="messages__item messages__item--operator">${item.message}</div>`;
        }
      });

    const chatmessage = chatbox.querySelector(".chatbox__messages");
    chatmessage.innerHTML = html;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const openButton = document.querySelector(".chatbox__button");
    const chatBox = document.querySelector(".chatbox__support");
    const sendButton = document.querySelector(".send__button");
    const node = chatBox.querySelector("input");

    openButton.addEventListener("click", () => toggleState(chatBox));

    sendButton.addEventListener("click", () => onSendButton(chatBox));

    node.addEventListener("keyup", ({ key }) => {
      if (key === "Enter") {
        onSendButton(chatBox);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="chatbox">
      {/* Your chatbox HTML structure goes here */}
      <button className="chatbox__button">
        <img src="./images/chatbox-icon.svg" alt="Chat" />
      </button>
      <div className={`chatbox__support ${state ? "chatbox--active" : ""}`}>
        {/* Your chatbox support HTML structure goes here */}
        <div className="chatbox__header">
          {/* Your chatbox header HTML structure goes here */}
          <div className="chatbox__image--header">
            <img
              src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/circled-user-female-skin-type-5--v1.png"
              alt="User"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="chatbox__content--header">
            <h4 className="chatbox__heading--header">Chat support</h4>
            <p className="chatbox__description--header">
              Hi. My name is Sam. How can I help you?
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="chatbox__messages">
          {/* Your chatbox messages HTML structure goes here */}
          {messages.map((item, index) => (
            <div
              key={index}
              className={`messages__item messages__item--${
                item.name === "Sam" ? "visitor" : "operator"
              }`}
            >
              {item.message}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="chatbox__footer">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Write a message..." />
          <button className="send__button">Send</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chatbox;
```

app.py (Flask Backend):

```
import sys
print("Python Interpreter Path:", sys.executable)

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from chat import get_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def index_get():
    return render_template("base.html")

@app.route("/predict", methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    text = request.get_json().get("message")
    # TO-DO: check if text is valid
    response = get_response(text)
    message = {"answer": response}
    return jsonify(message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=3000)
```

chat.py

```
import random
import json


import torch

from model import NeuralNet
from nltk_utils import bag_of_words, tokenize

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

with open('intents.json', 'r') as json_data:
    intents = json.load(json_data)

FILE = "data.pth"
data = torch.load(FILE)

input_size = data["input_size"]
hidden_size = data["hidden_size"]
output_size = data["output_size"]
all_words = data['all_words']
tags = data['tags']
model_state = data["model_state"]

model = NeuralNet(input_size, hidden_size, output_size).to(device)
model.load_state_dict(model_state)
model.eval()

bot_name = "Sam"

def get_response(msg):
    sentence = tokenize(msg)
    X = bag_of_words(sentence, all_words)
    X = X.reshape(1, X.shape[0])
    X = torch.from_numpy(X).to(device)

    output = model(X)
    _, predicted = torch.max(output, dim=1)

    tag = tags[predicted.item()]

    probs = torch.softmax(output, dim=1)
    prob = probs[0][predicted.item()]
    if prob.item() > 0.75:
        for intent in intents['intents']:
            if tag == intent["tag"]:
                return random.choice(intent['responses'])
    
    return "I do not understand..."


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Let's chat! (type 'quit' to exit)")
    while True:
        # sentence = "do you use credit cards?"
        sentence = input("You: ")
        if sentence == "quit":
            break

        resp = get_response(sentence)
        print(resp)
```

**Troubleshooting Steps Taken:**

1. Verified that the URL in the fetch request matches the Flask app's /predict endpoint.
2. Ensured that CORS is configured using the flask-cors library in the Flask app.
3. Restarted the Flask server to ensure it is running.
4. Checked console logs in both Flask server and browser for error messages.
5. Verified that all dependencies are correctly installed.
6. Checked file paths, locations, and server port.

**Question:**
Is there anything in my code that might be causing this "404 (Not Found)" error when making the fetch request? I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or solutions to help me resolve this issue. Thank you!

Note:

I am using React for the frontend and Flask for the backend.
The goal is to send a POST request from the chatbot interface in React to the /predict endpoint in Flask to get responses from the chatbot.
Both frontend and backend are running on the same port (port 3000).
The chatbot logic resides in chat.py and is imported into the Flask app.

Any help would be highly appreciated!